# 'RevMobAds/RevMobAds.h' file not found error

Tags: ios, xcode, revmob

I know that this question is asked a lot but i still couldn't get the right answer.

I just have followed the steps from the guide of the site [revmob](http://sdk.revmobmobileadnetwork.com/ios_full.html#configuration-swift).
I have did the cocoa pods part because i don't know how to make a pods file and my account is not in sudoers file so i can't use the sudo command in terminal. But do i need to do this part?

And yes i have already deleted and redroped the framework in Xcode.
This is how it look like:

[image: xcode[1]]

and in the project folder:

[image: project folder]

Those anybody know what is wrong?
Please let me know

UPDATE:

Could please someone help?
Or at least say if i need to do the cocoapods [part](http://sdk.revmobmobileadnetwork.com/ios_full.html#configuration-swift).

Comment: Did you or did you not use Cocoapods? It looks like you didn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this matter can be found [here](https://forum.revmobmobileadnetwork.com/topic/278/revmobads-revmobads-h-file-not-found-error):

> The issue is due XCode not correctly finding the RevMob framework.
>
> To correct the issue, what shall be done is to remove the framework,
>   and then redrop it. But, this time, make sure to check both the "Copy
>   items if needed" and "Create folder references" boxes.
>
> If all the other settings are right, as per the [tutorial](http://sdk.revmobmobileadnetwork.com/ios_full.html#configuration-swift), your
>   project should build now.

Answer (score 0):

If you dragged the framework into the project, there are a couple of things you need to troubleshoot.

You can either copy the files over (yellow folder) or make files paths to them (blue folder). If you make file paths, you have to set the "Framework Search Header" to that file/folder in your project's "Build Settings".

I've had the problem where if I don't copy over the files to the pre-made "Frameworks" group, I can't get the headers to import. Give that a try.